# Use xml comment to generate formatted html output

Tags: html, xml, xls

I'm trying to generate a nicely formatted html document from the comments that I have in an xml file. At present I have an xml file that is used to generate an html list of the xml tables. In order for me to add comments about the tables I am manually adding the comments into the output html file.

I would like If possible to put the html code in the xml file as a comment and have xslt use the comment to create the correctly formatted document.

Here is the part of the xml file that is commented. Here there is html new line syntax that I would like xslt to read as html. I'm thinking there must be a better way to use raw xml to create this but, I don't want the comments to be read in the xml file so don't want it as a table entry.

```
    <table name="ers_benchmark_defn" xmlns="">
    <!-- This table contains mapping between hierarchy nodes and their respective benchmarks.  The columns should be populated as follows:<br>
             <ul>
             <li>HIERARCHY_NODE<br>
             This column contains the name of the hierarchy node in the ERS Risk Hierarchy.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>BENCHMARK<br>
             The column can be populated with either;<br>
             a Calypso portfolio name,<br>
             an ERS Risk Hierarchy name, or<br>
             an ERS Risk Hierarchy node name.<br><br>
             In the latter case, the column should be populated with the hierarchy node name and the hierarchy to which it belongs, separated by a percentage symbol, %.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>BENCHMARK_TYPE<br>
             If the value in the benchmark column is an ERS hierarchy or hierarchy node name, this column should be populated with the value HIERARCHY.  Otherwise, when using a Calypso portfolio name, it should not be populated.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>SCALING_FACTOR<br>
             This column should be populated with the scaling factor by which the benchmark results should be multiplied.  To use MTM scaling, leave this column unpopulated.</ul>
             See the ERS 10.2 Release notes for further information.<br><br> -->
    <column name="hierarchy_node" nullable="false" type="string" scale="255"/>
    <column name="benchmark" nullable="false" type="string" scale="255"/>
    <column name="benchmark_type" nullable="true" type="string" scale="32"/>
    <column name="scaling_factor" nullable="true" type="float"/>
```

This is the part of the xsl file that I have made to use the comment, however it does not interpret the html.

```
<tr class="info" width="100%">
        <td colspan="4"><xsl:value-of select="comment()"/></td>
    </tr>
```

The required output looks like this when manually formatted:

```
  <p>
     <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="title">
           <th colspan="4"><a name="ers_benchmark_defn"></a>ers_benchmark_defn
           </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="info" width=100%>
             <th colspan=4 align=left>This table contains mapping between hierarchy nodes and their respective benchmarks.  The columns should be populated as follows:<br>
             <ul>
             <li>HIERARCHY_NODE<br>
             This column contains the name of the hierarchy node in the ERS Risk Hierarchy.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>BENCHMARK<br>
             The column can be populated with either;<br>
             a Calypso portfolio name,<br>
             an ERS Risk Hierarchy name, or<br>
             an ERS Risk Hierarchy node name.<br><br>
             In the latter case, the column should be populated with the hierarchy node name and the hierarchy to which it belongs, separated by a percentage symbol, %.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>BENCHMARK_TYPE<br>
             If the value in the benchmark column is an ERS hierarchy or hierarchy node name, this column should be populated with the value HIERARCHY.  Otherwise, when using a Calypso portfolio name, it should not be populated.</ul>
             <ul>
             <li>SCALING_FACTOR<br>
             This column should be populated with the scaling factor by which the benchmark results should be multiplied.  To use MTM scaling, leave this column unpopulated.</ul>
             See the ERS 10.2 Release notes for further information.<br><br></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header">
           <th>column name</th>
           <th>nullable</th>
           <th>type</th>
```

These are extracts of the full code but I think this should be enough for someone to help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I guess you are talking about **`<!CDATA[...]]>`** in XML files, check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) page about it.

In your example, I create a `comments` element (use the name you best like), and introduce `disable-output-escaping` attribute, to avoid HTML scaping.

It would go like this:

```
<table name="ers_benchmark_defn" xmlns="">
    <comments>
        <![CDATA[This table contains mapping between hierarchy nodes and their respective benchmarks.  The columns should be populated as follows:<br>
         <ul>
         <li>HIERARCHY_NODE<br>
         This column contains the name of the hierarchy node in the ERS Risk Hierarchy.</ul>
         <ul>
         <li>BENCHMARK<br>
         The column can be populated with either;<br>
         a Calypso portfolio name,<br>
         an ERS Risk Hierarchy name, or<br>
         an ERS Risk Hierarchy node name.<br><br>
         In the latter case, the column should be populated with the hierarchy node name and the hierarchy to which it belongs, separated by a percentage symbol, %.</ul>
         <ul>
         <li>BENCHMARK_TYPE<br>
         If the value in the benchmark column is an ERS hierarchy or hierarchy node name, this column should be populated with the value HIERARCHY.  Otherwise, when using a Calypso portfolio name, it should not be populated.</ul>
         <ul>
         <li>SCALING_FACTOR<br>
         This column should be populated with the scaling factor by which the benchmark results should be multiplied.  To use MTM scaling, leave this column unpopulated.</ul>
         See the ERS 10.2 Release notes for further information.<br><br>]]>
</comments>
<column name="hierarchy_node" nullable="false" type="string" scale="255"/>
<column name="benchmark" nullable="false" type="string" scale="255"/>
<column name="benchmark_type" nullable="true" type="string" scale="32"/>
<column name="scaling_factor" nullable="true" type="float"/>
```

In your XSL file:

```
<tr class="info" width="100%">
    <td colspan="4"><xsl:value-of select="comments" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></td>
</tr>
```

Ps: If you're still having problems with the output, try inserting this `xsl:output`line of XSL after your XML version declaration (more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp)):

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
```

Comment: Brilliant! A very good answer! If anyone else reads this disable-output-escaping is the correct syntax but it shouldn't take much googling to figure that out!

Comment: ups, you're right, i wrote it down badly at the end, i'm changing it!